# Choosing The Right IR Emitter for a Photodiode

Tags: led, communication, infrared

I am working with the following IR photodiode http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/bpv22nf.pdf

However, I am having some trouble figuring out what sort of IR emitter I can use with this. I am trying to setup simple IR data transfer between microcontrollers.  The datasheet makes me think I could use either a 950nm emitter or a 830-880nm emitter but I'm not entirely sure. Also, how closely should I match the rise and fall time? The beam angle? I'd like to use a through hole package, which may limit my choices.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all PIN photodiodes have very similar response curves. Check out figure 6 in the datasheet to see how the diode responds to different wavelengths. For instance, if you use an emitter at 850 nm instead of 950 nm, you'll only lose about 5% of the optical power, as compared to 950 nm. That's not much. If you look under the "Absolute Spectral Sensitivity" field in the Optical Characteristics table, you'll see how much current you get per watt of optical power. The angle in the datasheet should describe from what angles light will fall onto the photodiode. As the angle increases, the power will drop. It has a curved lens, so this will be mitagated a bit, but it's still a factor. Check out Figure 7 to see how this drops off.

What type of data will you be sending? You're going to want to hook this diode up to a [transimpedance amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current-to-voltage_converter) (a current to voltage amp) in order to get decent gain while preserving the bandwidth. As long as your datarate is minimal (< 100 kHz bandwidth, say) then it should be pretty straight forward.

If you're willing to change your receiver configuration, then I'd recommend looking at this chip: [OPT101](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/opt101.html). TI will send you 5 samples for free. I'm using this chip now and it's very nice - has a built in amplifier to make things easy. It also comes in a DIP package.

Answer (score 1):

well the data sheet says 'peak sensitivity' is 940nm but it will do 790-1050 - I'd say anything above 70-80% in Figure 6 should be OK.

As far as rise/fall times are concerned look at the signals you want to send: are they faster than signals you can send with the worst of the rise and fall times (and cut off freq) of the sender and receiver? - if so you should be OK

beam angle depends on how far you want to send the signal and the optics you're using

Answer (score 1):

i think you could also improve and broaden the beam angle if you were to use SMD parts, since its not all that hard to DIY.
as Taniwha pointed out the datasheet says it maxes out at 940, but i would go up to 1.1k maximum before i would start crossing my fingers :)

Comment: I'd like to use SMD parts but I don't have access to a reflow station.  Is there some hackish method to solder on SMD parts onto PCB without using a frying pan?

Comment: There is a way to use a little oven like this. http://www.real-onlineshop.de/medias/sys_master/products/000_099/010/011/0118891_001_001_xtralarge_1.jpg i dont know if you have access to such a device in the country where you live. in germany theyre sold in almost every shop. there is a tutorial to hack the device and control the temperature in a way that will melt the solder, but not harm the components. so yeah there is a way. i can point you to the tutorials if you like.